# Android ListView does not scroll. Tried everything

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

Okay i have a listView that does not Scroll. I tried everything that has been asked on SO.

1- I have enough items in the list to make it scrollable.

2- It is not in a ScrollView.

3- I have tried changing it's height to wrap_content and match_parent

4- I have an image in listview I have set focusable false.
Tried everything. I feel like giving up. This is my fragment_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/contacts"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:focusable="true"
tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_contacts" />
```

and this is fragment_contacts.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now am gonna give extra information if there is the problem.
i have main.xml which has a pager inside it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="context">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"

        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backscreen3"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="context"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
>
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: use recycleview insted of listview when using CoordinatorLayout

Comment: i guess this is the last option i have ???

Comment: did you used listview inside ScrollView?

Comment: Does listview scroll inside a simple LinearLayout wrapper this a simple example?

Comment: No i didn't @sasikumar

Comment: i haven't tried that @Vyacheslav

Comment: @UmerAsif , I wanna say just test your xml-files separately to chekc which block gives to you this unexpected result. This is hardly difficult to find this error remotely.

Comment: android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:focusable="true"          remove from your listview then try once again

Comment: @sasikumar no it didn't work when removed both you mentioned.

Comment: you got any error message

Comment: no just no scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `ListView` inside a `RelativeLayout` like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this Property in your ListView

```
  <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent">
```